# No "Edit Conflicts" option in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

This documentation: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-conflicts.html mentions a command `TortoiseGit -> Edit Conflicts`, but I've no such option. Is that command equivalent to `TortoiseGit -> Resolve...`? Or is there some prerequisite that I have to meet for the option to show up? I do have existing conflicts, assuming that's one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TortoiseGit -> Edit Conflicts` is only available on conflicted files. Whereas `TortoiseGit -> Resolve...` is also available on folders in case there is at least one conflict in your repository.

`Edit Conflicts` opens a conflict editor that allows to resolve the conflict in the file, whereas `Resolve...` opens a dialog which lists all conflicted files and allows to "clear" the conflicted state on the checked files (or use the context menu there in order to perform other resolve options for a file).

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-conflicts.html

Answer (score 1):

The passage of the "Daily Usage Guide" (DUG) is:

> You can use any editor to manually resolve the conflict or you can launch an external merge tool/conflict editor with TortoiseGit → Edit Conflicts

But that implies there is a conflict to begin with.

Typically, you are merging/rebasing, and the process stops for you to resolve conflicts.
*Then* you should see that option, provided you have files with conflict markers.

But since you do have existing conflicts, do check your `git config` options, to see if a `mergetool` was defined.